# Use default mappings with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using `AutoMapper` to map a set of `Models` to `ViewModels`. It all works fine, but i have to keep doing one thing over and over again for every model/viewmodel that i create. I have to map a certain attribute from (for example) `String` to `Int`.

So my mapping now looks something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ModelOne, ModelOneViewModel>()
    .ForMember (d => d.SomeProperty, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(t => Convert.ToString(t.SomeProperty)));

Mapper.CreateMap<ModelOneViewModel, ModelOne>()
    .ForMember (d => d.SomeProperty, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.SomeProperty)));

Mapper.CreateMap<ModelTwo, ModelTwoViewModel>()
    .ForMember (d => d.SomeProperty, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(t => Convert.ToString(t.SomeProperty)));

// ... etc
```

Is there a way to tell automapper that it should always map `SomeProperty` to a `String` when it maps from my `Models` class to my `ViewModels` class?

And vice versa, is it then possible to tell automapper to always map the property `SomeProperty` back to an `Int32` when it maps from `ViewModels` back to `Models`?

Comment: to be clear, you want the conversion to be based on the property name of `ModelOne` (or visa versa for the view model) ? Should that be `ModelOne.SomeProperty` or any property with name `SomeProperty` ?

Comment: @wal Both the ModelXXX and ModelXXXViewModel have the same property name. Its is always called `SomeProperty`. In `ModelXXX` this is always an `Int32` and in `ModelXXXViewModel` its always a `String`. -- So when i map from `ModelXXX` *to* `ModelXXXViewModel`, then it should **map** `SomeProperty` from `Int32` to `String`. - When i **map** from ModelXXXViewModel *to* ModelXXX, then it should always cast `SomeProperty` from `String` to `Int32`.

Comment: @w00 Isn't [Custom Type Converters](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters) what you're looking for?

Comment: as per the doctors link, would adding a general conversion (not just for that property) be acceptable? eg:
`Mapper.CreateMap<string, int>().ConvertUsing(Convert.ToInt32);`

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor I think that could be useful. I'm actually trying to convert a `byte[]` to a `string` (converting to base64) and vice versa. A `string` (base64) back to `byte[]`. For some reason my `Convert` method isn't getting triggered yet. But i think it solves my problem when i get this working. Could you perhaps add it as an answer (and extra info, if you have any), so i can accept it later on, when no other answers are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment request, the [Custom Type Converters](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) may come in handy in your case.

I don't have any additional information for now, good thing the mentioned article looks like it's
explaining things quite well.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the issue i had earlier. It's already working like a charm!